# Promise used for async rendering, but doesn't remain resolved after navigation

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, promise

I have a template set up watching a `Promise<boolean>` with `async` so that the table will only render once data has made it to the component. However, if I navigate to another page and then come back to that component, the table won't render anymore, even though the Promise was previously resolved and the data has been stored locally in the component.

Am I just fundamentally misunderstanding how Promises work? Do I need to store something in session storage and use that once a Promise is resolved?

The reason I was doing this was because I make an asynchronous call to my database but I only want to do it when absolutely necessary. So the call to resolve the Promise happens only when initially fetching data and subsequent fetches after pushing an update to the database. Is it not preserved when the component is navigated away from?

EDIT: Including some basic example code for clarification

**app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.service.fetchData();
}
```

**service.ts**

```
fetchData = function () {
    return this.http
    .get(url)
    .subscribe((data, err) => {
        ...
        this.eventSubject.next(data);
    })
}
```

**data-component.ts**

```
...
    ngOnInit(){
        this.dataSub = this.service.event$.subscribe((data) => {
            process(data);
        });
    ...
    }

    process = function(data) {
        // format data
        ...
        this.data = formattedData;
        this.dataLoaded = Promise.resolve(true);
    }
```

**data-template.html**

```
<table *ngIf="dataLoaded | async">
    <!-- Data only renders first time page is loaded -->
</table>
```

Comment: *"the data has been stored locally in the component"* - but when you leave and return it's probably a *different instance* of the component. Typically you'd store the data in a *service*, so the new instance can access it (I wrote about one pattern for this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html). Without a [mcve] it's hard to say more.

Comment: what is `eventSubject`?